# Como ignorar um erro no R?

Tags: r, funções

Criei uma função dentro, contudo, se em algum ponto ocorrer um erro, não me é importante e quero que ela prossiga até o final, ignorando o erro.

```
valor<-1
Erro<-function(valor){
  valor<-valor+1
  print(valor)
  valor<-valor+1
  print(valor)
  na.fail(NA)
  valor<-valor+1
  print(valor)
  valor<-valor+1
  print(valor)
}
Erro(valor)
```

E quais repercussões disso?

Comment: Não sei se é isto que quer: `tryCatch(na.fail(NA), error = function(e) print(e))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há vários modos de processar erros disponíveis no R, talvez o mais frequentemente usado seja a função [`tryCatch`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html).

```
Erro <- function(valor){
  valor <- valor + 1
  print(valor)
  valor <- valor + 1
  print(valor)
  err <- tryCatch(na.fail(NA), error = function(e) e)
  if(inherits(err, "error")) print(err)
  valor <- valor + 1
  print(valor)
  valor <- valor + 1
  print(valor)
}

valor <- 1
Erro(valor)
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#<simpleError in na.fail.default(NA): missing values in object>
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
```

Outra boa referência é o [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html) do Hadley Wickham.